# SharePoint search not show any result?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results

SharePoint search not Display result .It always display below message 
[image]

Comment: can you share your search query?

Comment: Actually I don't about sharepoint search.where is search query ?

Comment: edit the page, in search result webpart->edit webpart->change query

Comment: I don't want this in web part

Answer (score 2):

Please create and configure a Search service application in SharePoint Server 2013 follow the article below:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597.aspx

Then do the full crawl.